# Mean value inequality in calculus of several variables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

We know that if $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, $f:\Omega\to \mathbb R$ is a differentiable function, $\mathbf a,\mathbf b\in \Omega$ such that $S=\{(1-t)\mathbf a+t\mathbf b:t\in [0,1]\}\subset \Omega$, then there exists $\mathbf c\in S$ such that $f(\mathbf b)-f(\mathbf a)=f^{\prime}(\mathbf c)(\mathbf b-\mathbf a)$. But this not in general true if $f$ is a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R^m$.

I want to prove that if $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, $f:\Omega\to \mathbb R^m$ is a differentiable function, $\mathbf a,\mathbf b\in \Omega$ such that $S=\{(1-t)\mathbf a+t\mathbf b:t\in [0,1]\}\subset \Omega$, then there exists $\mathbf c\in S$ such that $\|f(\mathbf b)-f(\mathbf a)\|\leq\|f^{\prime}(\mathbf c)(\mathbf b-\mathbf a)\|$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got an answer to this question.

We know that for any $u\in \mathbb R^m$, we have $\mathbf u.(f(\mathbf b)-f(\mathbf a))=\mathbf u.(f^{\prime}(\mathbf c)(\mathbf {b-a}))$. Putting $\mathbf u=\frac{f(\mathbf b)-f(\mathbf a)}{\|f(\mathbf b)-f(\mathbf a)\|}$ we get $\|f(\mathbf b)-f(\mathbf a)\|\leq \|f^{\prime}(\mathbf c)(\mathbf {b-a})\|$ by Cauchy-Scwarz inequality.